# Execute JavaScript on Key Press

Tags: javascript, function, keyboard, keypress

I am trying to add a script to my website that is only executed on key press, using JavaScript to handle the event. They specific key to be pressed is the one located below the "esc" key; the "`" key. I have found that the code for this key is 192, where the "Enter" key is 13 if that makes sense.

Here is the code I currently have & I don't understand why it isn't working:

```
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 192) {
        //CODE I WANT TO EXECUTE GOES HERE
  }
})
```

Please help! I would use HTML but it is for a single .js file included on different pages around different sites. Also, I have read that there is code that only does this while in focus and I need it to work anywhere on the page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code is actually 96. Try logging the key code.

Answer (score 0):

27 is the code for the escape key. You can find the hex code for all the characters in this link (http://asciitable.com/). Try this,

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 27 || e.keyCode === 27) {
        //CODE I WANT TO EXECUTE GOES HERE
    }
});
```

Comment: How about use keyup instead of keypress?